# FreeBSD on RPi doesn't see TP-Link wifi dongle

Tags: freebsd, wifi, raspberry-pi

I've installed FreeBSD 10 on a Raspberry Pi via [Crochet](https://github.com/kientzle/crochet-freebsd/). I'm trying to get it to work with a [TP-Link TL-WN727N v3](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN727N_v3) USB wifi adapter, which [should be supported](http://www.freebsd.org/relnotes/CURRENT/hardware/support.html) and [seems to work for others](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=43895&sid=1a41741e221ed444ad398657f97514d3) (though presumably on more standard hardware) via the [`run`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=run&sektion=4) driver. However, though I can see a message in `dmesg` when the device is connected, I don't seem to see something indicating that the driver recognizes it and can use it, nor does `ipconfig` seem to want to have anything to do with it.

Here's all that appears in `dmesg` when I connect the dongle:

```
ugen0.4: <TPlink> at usbus0
```

I should be seeing more messages from `run`, right? At any rate, `ifconfig` does not abide:

```
Pi ~> sudo ifconfig wlan0 create wlandev run0
ifconfig: SIOCIFCREATE2: Device not configured
```

The instance of the system that Crochet creates was pretty bare-bones, so I can't help but wonder if I'm missing a needed kernel module or something, but I'm not sure what I could be missing. Here's output that may be relevant…

```
Pi ~> cat /boot/loader.conf 
ehci_load="YES"
uhci_load="YES"
ohci_load="YES"
usb_load="YES"
wlan_load="YES"
wlan_wep_load="YES"
wlan_ccmp_load="YES"
wlan_tkip_load="YES"
wlan_amrr_load="YES"

if_run_load="YES"
runfw_load="YES"

Pi ~> kldstat
Id Refs Address    Size     Name
 1   27 0xc0100000 5b0290   kernel
 2    1 0xc06b1000 222f0    if_run.ko
 3    3 0xc06d4000 ae48     firmware.ko
 4    6 0xc06df000 5b51c    wlan.ko
 6    1 0xc0751000 1391c    uhci.ko
 7    1 0xc0765000 12fac    ohci.ko
 8    1 0xc0778000 a024     wlan_wep.ko
 9    1 0xc0783000 e418     wlan_ccmp.ko
10    1 0xc0792000 b3c4     wlan_tkip.ko
11    1 0xc079e000 9c18     wlan_amrr.ko
12    1 0xc07a8000 ac34     runfw.ko
```

So `ehci` isn't loading, though it doesn't load manually either, and at any rate I don't know if that's relevant to this…

```
Pi ~> sudo kldload ehci
kldload: can't load ehci: No such file or directory
Pi ~> ls /boot/kernel/ehci.ko
/boot/kernel/ehci.ko
```

What should I look at next?

EDIT: `usbconfig` output by request:

```
Pi ~> sudo usbconfig
…
ugen0.4: <802.11 n WLAN TPlink> at usbus0, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=ON (450mA)
```

Comment: If FreeBSD(10) has `lsusb` Linux USB utility then please post the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: It doesn't have `lsusb`, but it does have `usbconfig` which sounds like what you're looking for. I edited its output into the OP. As you can see, it can see the USB device just fine, and eve seems to recognize it as a WLAN adapter…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the "release" of FreeBSD 10 does not include the code that made using the chipset in this adapter, Ralink RT5370, possible. I didn't think that made sense since as per that forum thread the commit to the code to use it was made well before the FreeBSD 10 release, but it seems to be the case. Compare the code if if_run.c in the [releng branch](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/releng/10.0/sys/dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c?revision=259065&view=markup&pathrev=259457) versus in the oddly-named [stable](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/10/sys/dev/usb/wlan/if_run.c?view=markup&pathrev=259453) branch - the former makes no mention of the RT5370, whereas the latter has it in there.

I think what I need to do is go back to the VM I ran Crochet in, replace /usr/src (which IIRC was put there by the installer) with a fresher SVN checkout, then have Crochet build a new disk image off of it. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Have you succeeded?

Comment: This was quite a while ago, but yes, I remember getting this working.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a Raspberry Pi 2 and the FreeBSD 11.0 image downloaded from freebsd.org. My WiFi dongle uses the same RT5370 and also appears to be recognized, but I can't get it to appear in ifconfig. Any clues?